# how can I user for with setTimeout?

Tags: javascript

I have this loop. When I try pass the `i` with `setTimeout` I get a same result in each cycle " The final result of `i` ".

```
  for( var i = 0; i < step.length; i++  ){

      setTimeout( function(   ){

          insideJMove.doMove( i );

      } , 1000 ); 

    }
```

How can I get different value of `i`  inside `setTimeout` in each cycle ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways you can get around this. This happens because the scope of variable defined with `var` is its current execution context. Making `i` a global variable that will be reused in your loop.

Use the let keyword:

> [let] works as intended because the instances of the (anonymous) inner function [of the for loop] refer to different instances of the variable i

This is because:

> Variables declared by let have as their scope the block in which they are defined, as well as in any contained sub-blocks

```
for( let i = 0; i < step.length; i++  ){

    setTimeout( function(   ){

        insideJMove.doMove( i );

    } , 1000 ); 

}
```

or Immediately Invoked Function Expression

This creates a new execution context where the value of `i` stays as whatever it was when the function expression was executed.

```
for( var i = 0; i < step.length; i++  ){
    (function(i){
        setTimeout( function(   ){

            insideJMove.doMove( i );

        } , 1000 ); 
    })(i);

}
```

Comment: It is actually called IIFE (immediately-invoked function expression).

Answer (score 1):

Use `let` instead of `var`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < step.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    insideJMove.doMove(i);
  } , 1000 );     
}
```

See [What's the difference between using "let" and "var" to declare a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/let-keyword-vs-var-keyword).

Answer (score 0):

**setTimeout** runs asynchronous so loop will be over when it will call first setTimeout, so **variable i** will has it last value in loop.

One of solutions is to use **recursion**:

```
var i=0;
function loop(){

    insideJMove.doMove( i );

    if (i<step.length)
    setTimeout(loop,1000);

    i++;
}

loop();//start our loop
```